# Accepted/Declined/Finished - statuses (flag) for a record in database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, flags

which will be the best approach for a table design for keeping statuses for a product:

- Product Accepted
- Product Declined
- Product Finished (Shipped)

These are my ideas:

1. a int field for "accepted" another for "declined" and another for "finished" (with values 0 or 1)
2. a datetime for each "accepted", "declined" and "finished" (by default the field will be NULL)
3. just a field "status" with values 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the status can only be one of those three at any time, then there should only be one field. So, your third idea would be correct. Having three fields when only one is necessary would be a waste of storage space, so should be avoided.

The best solution is to simply have a `status` field that holds which one of the three statuses the product is at. This will also make adding or removing a status easy since you will only have to modify the code to insert a different value, not the database itself.

If you do need the date at which the status was last changed to also be stored, you could have a field called `last_status_change` which is a datetime and you update to the current time whenever you change the status.

Comment: A product by default doesn't have any status. Then the user can accept or decline the product. If the product is accepted then I need to update also the "finished" status, when the product is shipped.

Comment: Then this is fine. Have `null` allowed and make it the default value for the field. Then, when the user accepts it change the status to `1` and when it is shipped, change it to `3`. If it is rejected, change it to `2`.

Comment: This doesn't create some kind of confusion? Maybe I should also keep a table product_statuses where to have explanation for each status 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: If you wish, you can definitely track changes (what was the change, who made it, when was it made, etc.) in some kind of logging table, but as far as this table is concerned, the most efficient solution is to just use one field, as anything else will just be a waste of storage space (if the status can only be one thing at any given time, why have three fields for it?).

Comment: @EdoDodo, it's useful if you need to know when the status was changed over time. For example tracking a package, or processing an order (which it seems like the OP is doing with this system).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how detailed you want future reporting to be. Your options 1 and 3 are effectively the same, so throw out option 1 in favor of the better option 3.

Now you're left with two options, and to pick one you need to answer the following:

*Do I want to know **when** each status was set, or just **if**?*

Personally, I would choose option 2 just in case you want to add any detailed reporting capability in the future. The DATETIME fields will take more space than a single INT, but in most cases this isn't a problem.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(64),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `product_status` (
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `status_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(`product_id`, `status_id`)
)
```

That way, you have the flexibility of all different kinds of status fields, and by using the many-to-many table you gain the ability to see when each status was set. Plus, if you're using InnoDB tables you can set up [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html).

To query a product:

```
SELECT s.title, ps.date
FROM status s
LEFT JOIN product_status ps ON (s.id = ps.status_id)
WHERE (ps.product_id = MYPID)
```

Comment: For now I don't need to know when a status was set. But you never know when a user can ask you "I didn't declined the product, when I do that?" :D

Comment: @morandi3: I updated the answer with another option that might work better for you. It is a bit more complex than a simple INT status field, but gives you the benefit of variable status fields as well as status change tracking for each type of status.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation of your 3rd option is some enum or else. But int is always a better idea. For performance may be even tinyint (less bytes).

But you should have then some product_status (id, name) table with 3 records.